# How Do I Get Python Dictionary to Fill HTML Select Option with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, dictionary

If a user selects a `#bundle`, it takes the request through Ajax to this Django view.

```
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def getcourses(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        id = int(request.POST['cat_id'])
        try:
            courses = Courses.objects.values('id', 'name').filter(cat_id = id)
        except Courses.DoesNotExist:
            courses = None
        if courses:
            message = courses
            return HttpResponse(message)
        else:
            message = 'Please select a valid bundle...'
            return HttpResponse(message)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('mysite:index'))
```

The view returns this dictionary:

```
{'id': 1L, 'name': u'Python'}
{'id': 2L, 'name': u'Django'}
{'id': 3L, 'name': u'jQuery'}
{'id': 4L, 'name': u'Ajax'}
```

*How do I remove these Ls?*

What I want is to have this dictionary iterated over in jQuery and have them as options under `#courses` in my HTML.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="selectbasic">Select a bundle...</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select id="bundle" name="bundle" class="form-control input-xlarge">
            <option class = 'selected-value' value = '1'>Web Design</option>
            <option class = 'selected-value' value = '2'>Mobile Apps</option>
        </select>
        <select id="courses" name="courses" class="form-control input-xlarge">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My jQuery code**:

```
$(document).on('change', '#bundle', function(){
    var $this = $( this );
    var $cat_id = $this.val()
    if ($cat_id.length > 0){
        var request = $.ajax({
          url: "/mysite/fetchcourses/",
          type: "POST",
          data: { cat_id : $cat_id },
          dataType: "html"
        });
        request.done(function( msg ) {
            $.each(msg, function (i, item) {
                $('#courses').append($('<option>', { 
                    value: item.id,
                    text : item.name 
                        }));
                    });
        });
        request.fail(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('errorThrown '+ errorThrown);
        })
    }
})
```

How do I get the dictionary data iterated over and have them as option under `#courses`? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: int() is sufficient to make 1L->1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it to json.

```
import json 

... 

 if courses:
        message = list(courses)
        response =  HttpResponse(json.dumps(message), content_type ='application/json' )
        return response
```

Now you can treat your response like a javascript object.

Comment: I tried this but it says `Exception Type: TypeError at /mysite/fetchcourses/
Exception Value: [{'id': 1L, 'name': u'Python'}....] is not JSON serializable
`

Comment: Did that but it returns `Exception Type: AttributeError at /mysite/fetchcourses/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_cookie'`

Comment: That probably has something to do with your csrf cookie. What does the form posting to this view look like?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, by form posting you mean the route to the view?

Comment: yes... my suspicion is that you don't need the @ensure_csrf_cookie decorator, and you can just do {% csrf_token %} in your template

Comment: I have that in my template. That should do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61513/discussion-between-isaac-ray-and-yax).